# Convert attribute value into element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform this xml:

```
<tokens>
 <token cle="a">
  <token cle="b">nomX</token>
  <token cle="c">prenomX</token>
  <token cle="d">villeX</token>
 </token>
 <token cle="a">
  <token cle="b">nomY</token>
  <token cle="c">prenomY</token>
  <token cle="d">villeY</token>
 </token>
 <token cle="e">nomZ</token>
</tokens>
```

into this xml:

```
<tokens>
 <a>
  <b>nomX</b>
  <c>prenomX</c>
  <d>villeX</d>
 </a>
 <a>
  <b>nomY</b>
  <c>prenomY</c>
  <d>villeY</d>
 </a>
 <e>nomZ</e>
</tokens>
```

so convert the attribute value into an element , but i need to keep the whole structure and deph.

I've tried using XSL, but i didn't succeed yet.
If anyone has an idea, it would be  greatly appreciated.

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so xslt is the right way I think:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="token">
        <xsl:element name="{@cle}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good answer. Good use of the identity transform :)

Comment: Note that to force the interpretation of `@cle` in the xsl:element's name attribute, you need to surround it with curvy brackets. Otherwise the XSLT processor will complain that you cannot name an element `@cle`.  I needed to create an element name from a variable and my XSLT processor kept complaining that `$varName` was not a valid name for an element. Changing to `<xsl:element name="{$varName}">` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="token">
  <xsl:element name="{@cle}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

for more info on xsl:element see:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element

you might want to add some xsl:if to check if there really is a @cle attribute, but otherwise this should work fine

Comment: no this works not at all: first you lost the content of token`an second you have to aa {} arround @cle for element name.

Comment: Hi thx for the quick response, it has really help me to find the answer here is what i use:<xsl:template match="token">
  <xsl:element name="{@cle}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

I used your answer to find the right xsl:

here is what i use:

```
<xsl:template match="token">
        <xsl:element name="{@cle}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Thank a lot !