# copy attribute to closing tag

Tags: xml, tags, copy

I have a huge xml file which I want to import into Excel.  As part of this, I need the opening and closing tags to match.

this is a snippet of what I am starting with:

```
    <FIELD NAME="language">en</FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="languages"></FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="charset"></FIELD>
<FIELD NAME="urls"></FIELD>
```

etc

I need it to transform to this

```
    <"language">en</"language">
<"languages"></"languages">
<"charset"></"charset">
<"urls"></"urls">
```

There is sometimes a number, sometimes a date, sometimes a URL and some times a ton of text in between the tags.

can anyone suggest an approach?  thanks

Comment: You output is bogus XML.

Comment: I don't need it to be valid xml, i need to get it so that when it goes into excel the opening and closing tags matches so that the stuff that is written to do analysis in excel (that I can't change) can look at stuff between matching tags

Comment: So excel understands your broken XML? I dont think so.

Comment: We don't import it as xml, we paste the output of this so that we have a tag text tag and then look at the text between the matching tags, that is what I understand anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a XLST to transform the xml file prior to import 
or process it using regex

Note: as the comment implies, your output is invalid, you cannot contain quotes in the xml element names

I would also see this answer [Convert attribute value into element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733880/convert-attribute-value-into-element)

Comment: I know neither xslt nor regex - could you let me know which approach is easier?

Comment: I would suggest xslt this is somethign like you want http://www.itjungle.com/mgo/mgo101003-story01.html google for xslt tutorials and use a product like oxygen or other xml handler