# XSLT to remove node and convert atrribute value to element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="somename">
        <node1></node1>
        <node2></node2>
    </lst>
    <result name="somename" count="5">
        <doc>
            <str name="NodeA">ValueA</str>
            <str name="NodeB">ValueB</str>
            <str name="NodeC">ValueC</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <str name="NodeA">ValueD</str>
            <str name="NodeB">ValueE</str>
            <str name="NodeC">ValueF</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

which i want to convert to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <doc>
        <NodeA>ValueA</NodeA>
        <NodeB>ValueB</NodeB>
        <NodeC>ValueC</NodeC>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <NodeA>ValueD</NodeA>
        <NodeB>ValueE</NodeB>
        <NodeC>ValueF</NodeC>
    </doc>
</response>
```

As you can see the lst node is completely removed and the attribute values have now become nodes.

First i used this xslt code to remove the lst node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="lst"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gave me this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <result name="somename" count="5">
        <doc>
            <str name="NodeA">ValueA</str>
            <str name="NodeB">ValueB</str>
            <str name="NodeC">ValueC</str>
        </doc>
        <doc>
            <str name="NodeA">ValueD</str>
            <str name="NodeB">ValueE</str>
            <str name="NodeC">ValueF</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

Then used this xslt from the link [link] [Convert attribute value into element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733880/convert-attribute-value-into-element)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="response/result/doc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="token">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it didn't help. It gave me this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc>ValueAValueBValueC</doc>
<doc>ValueDValueEValueF</doc>
```

Please help me with the second part which converts attribute values to nodes.
Is it possible to have one xslt do both these things?

Comment: What is the question/where are you stuck?

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have got so far, so we can see/point out what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Post updated. Please check.

Comment: Well - `<xsl:template match="token">` refers to an element named `token`, but there is no such element in your source document. So, what is that rule supposed to apply to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve all your goals here in one XSLT that's very close to your current one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- copy everything as-is apart from exceptions below -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- delete lst -->
    <xsl:template match="lst"/>

    <!-- strip out the result element but still include its children -->
    <xsl:template match="result">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- convert str name="X" to X -->
    <xsl:template match="str">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Worked exactly as i wanted it to Ian. Thank you especially for the self explanatory comments placed before each lines of code.

Comment: One weird issue.
When we have an empty node in the source xml, the xslt would put the closing tag for such node in the next line instead of same line.

As a result we have the new line characters in the data when such a file is imported.

For instance this
 <str name="NodeA"/>
is transformed to
 <NodeA>
 </NodeA>
But should ideally have been tranformed to either this
 <NodeA/>
or this
 <NodeA></NodeA>

Any solution for this issue?

Comment: @user1677271 the `<xsl:strip-space>` should handle that if the nodes are genuinely completely empty, provided it's the XSLT processor that is responsible for parsing the original XML file.  If you're handing the XSLT processor a pre-parsed DOM document rather than letting it parse the XML then it may not strip the whitespace-only text nodes.  You can handle this at the XSLT level though, by adding an `<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]" />`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as a basis

XSL how to copy all elements except for ones called annotation

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="*|/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- copy xsd:annotation and children, but don't copy the attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="xsd:annotation">

        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </xsd:annotation>

    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="lst"/>

  <xsl:template match="str[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates  />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<response>
  <result>
    <doc>
      <NodeA>ValueA</NodeA>
      <NodeB>ValueB</NodeB>
      <NodeC>ValueC</NodeC>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <NodeA>ValueD</NodeA>
      <NodeB>ValueE</NodeB>
      <NodeC>ValueF</NodeC>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```