# Select nodes below certain node and convert attribute values into elements

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<A someattributes>
   <B someotherattributes>
      <Value XX="Attr1">SomeInfo1</Value>
      <Value XX="Attr2"></Value>
      <Value XX="Attr3">SomeInfo3</Value>
      <Value XX="Attr4">SomeInfo4</Value>
   </B>
</A>
```

My XSLT shall generate the following output:

```
<IMPORT>
   <Attr1>SomeInfo1</Attr1>
   <Attr3>SomeInfo3</Attr3>
   <Attr4>SomeInfo4</Attr4>
</IMPORT>
```

So, my requirements are

- The top node shall be "**IMPORT**" (all nodes above "Value" shall be removed)
- All attribute values of attribute "**XX**" shall be converted to elements
- If an element has no value (like **XX="Attr2"** in the above example), it shall not be added.

For the conversion between attributes and elements I tried to follow this thread:
[Convert attribute value into element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733880/convert-attribute-value-into-element)

But unfortunately I am unable to adapt it to get the output I described above (IMPORT node, exclude empty elements)

Here is what I have, but it doesn't produce the right output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <!--<xsl:template match="/">-->
        <IMPORT>
            <xsl:for-each select="Value">
                <xsl:call-template name="iter">
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </IMPORT>
    </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template name="iter">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Value">
      <xsl:element name="{@XX}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not do something simple like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <IMPORT>
        <xsl:for-each select="B/Value[@XX][text()]">
            <xsl:element name="{@XX}">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </IMPORT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted, thanks :) I forgot to mention that I am a beginner in XSLT :)